# How do I change the minecraft menu song?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was making a new Soundtrack for Minecraft using a resourcepack I have the .OGG file I want to play and I have it in `.minecraft\resourcepacks\(My Resourcepack Name)\assets\minecraft\sounds\menu` the song's file name is `got.OGG`

I have changed the records but I dont know how to change the menu's song.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do what colorfusion said but change the files to read-only, Minecraft will just replace the music :/ You can do this by right-clicking the files and then clicking 'Properties'. Next, tick 'Read-Only' and then hit apply and ok.

-The reason I didn't comment is because I don't have enough reputation as I created my account literally 43 seconds ago.

Comment: That's no reason to post a comment as an answer. However, in this case it should be rather easy to expand this to a proper, self sufficent answer. You can even include details from *colorfusion*'s answer, if you attribute them properly.

Answer (score 2):

Rename the file to `menu1.ogg`. You may also need to overwrite the other menu music files by duplicating your song and calling it `menu2.ogg`, `menu3.ogg` and `menu4.ogg`.

Comment: I have tied that and when I go to the main menu it just plays the normal C418 music, do you have anything else that might work?

Answer (score -2):

This can be done using Resource Packs.

Comment: Could you explain how to accomplish it with Resource Packs?